# How to forward new email to next team member using VBA?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I run a sales team and we get referrals in our team inbox. I manually forward each new referral to my team members and this is a huge waste of time.

I'm looking to forward each new referral email to the next team member.

Receive new email - send to team member 1
Receive new email - send to team member 2
Receive new email - send to team member 3

Receive new email - send to team member 1
Receive new email - send to team member 2
Receive new email - send to team member 3

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Have not found any existed script which is based on the incoming message order. And if there is network congestion, issues might happen due to the possible abnormal receiving order.

Why not adding some specific "marks" between those difference email messages and then the part of "Find a code in the message body, then forward" in this article might be helpful to you. https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-script-rule-change-subject-message/

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

' Convert to ItemAdd code to do this automatically

' Avoid global variables unless there is no other way
'  Inevitably the name will be non-unique
'  You need something improbable to reproduce in other code
Public nextEmp20210216 As Long  ' starts at 0 when Outlook opens, unless last value saved

Private Sub AssignMail()

Dim myFolder As folder
Dim myFolderItem As Object  ' not necessarily a mailitem

Dim myFolderItems As Items
Dim myFolderItemsCount As Long

Dim myFilteredItems As Items
Dim myFilteredItemsCount As Long

Dim i As Long
Dim myMail As MailItem
Dim forwardMail As MailItem

Dim empArray() As String    ' zero-based array

' rotate elements if no code to equitably assign the first mail
empArray = Split("addr0@domain.com,addr1@domain.com,addr2@domain.com", ",")

For i = LBound(empArray) To UBound(empArray)
    Debug.Print i & ": " & empArray(i)
Next i

Debug.Print "UBound(empArray): " & UBound(empArray)

'RetrieveStorageData
' https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.getstorage
' Could instead use a text file, or Excel workbook, or ...

Debug.Print " starting nextEmp20210216: " & nextEmp20210216

If nextEmp20210216 > UBound(empArray) Then
    ' can occur if array elements reduced since last run
    nextEmp20210216 = 0
End If

Set myFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'Set myFolder = myFolder.folders("Test")

Set myFolderItems = myFolder.Items

myFolderItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

myFolderItemsCount = myFolderItems.count
Debug.Print " myFolderItemsCount..: " & myFolderItemsCount

' Simple method to stop repeats.
Set myFilteredItems = myFolder.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
myFilteredItemsCount = myFilteredItems.count
Debug.Print " myFilteredItemsCount: " & myFilteredItemsCount

For i = myFilteredItemsCount To 1 Step -1

    If TypeOf myFilteredItems(i) Is MailItem Then
        
        Set myMail = myFilteredItems(i)
        Set forwardMail = myMail.Forward
        
        With forwardMail
            Debug.Print .subject
            Debug.Print " current nextEmp20210216: " & nextEmp20210216
            .To = empArray(nextEmp20210216)
            Debug.Print "  " & .To
            
            ' Resolve recipients if not using email addresses.
            '  Never fails with email address format - addr0@domain.com.
            '.Recipients.ResolveAll
            
            .Display    ' change to .send
        End With
        
        With myMail
        
            ' Simple method to stop repeats
            .UnRead = False
            
            ' If necessary, for better evidence mail was assigned with this code
            
            ' 1 - Since this is a reverse For Loop
            '     can move myMail to "Assigned" folder
            
            ' Or
            
            ' 2 - Mark, perhaps with a category
            '.categories = "Green Category"
            '.Save   ' required when updating categories
            
        End With
        
        nextEmp20210216 = (nextEmp20210216 + 1) Mod (UBound(empArray) + 1)
        Debug.Print " future  nextEmp20210216: " & nextEmp20210216
        
    End If
    
Next

'AssignStorageData
' https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.getstorage

End Sub
```